# How to enable CORS in laravel 8 for Google Translate API

Tags: php, laravel, http, cors

i'm figuring how to use CORS in laravel 8. My local website is located at http://127.0.0.1:8000 and I want to send request to https://translate.googleapis.com but, I always get this error :

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=id&tl=en&dt=t&q=%20rapat%20kelas%20a%20membicarakan%20tentang%20kemajuan%20smp%20kunugigaoka'
> from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

and my CORS is :

```
<?php

return [
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => [],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

until now, I don't know how to use or disable it.

Comment: CORS is something enabled on the server, in this case `translate.googleapis.com` which you cannot control. Your problem also has nothing to do with Laravel since only requests from JS running in the browser are subject to CORS policy. Google does not offer a browser-based JS SDK for Cloud Translate so you'll need to make requests from the server-side

Comment: You can use your Laravel app to proxy requests from the browser through to Google. I recommend you check out the [PHP client library](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v2/php)